# Modifying the returned Map value type with collectors.groupingBy in Java stream

Tags: java, java-8

I have below the class definition of `Entry` -

```
public class Entry {
    private String key;
    private String Value;
    // getters and setters
    // equals hashcode toString
}
```

I got List of `Entry` objects from database.
I want to group them based on key and values of the result Map should be `Set<value>`.

I tried and end up with the below code.

```
Map<String, Set<Entry>> groupedEntries =  
        entryList.findAll()
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ek -> ek.getKey().toLowerCase(), Collectors.toSet()));
```

The problem with this code is the result type is `Map<String, Set<Entry>>` but I want to be `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

is it possible to do this in single collect?

Comment: you are grouping by `ek -> ek.getPlatform()`. Does it correspond to the key or the value?

Comment: Hi Arnaud - I have updated my question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the `mapping` collector:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ek -> ek.getKey().toLowerCase(), 
                  Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collector.toSet())));
```

Comment: but the answer is always the same

Comment: @Eugene déjà vu. couldn't agree more ^_^ .